# Unable to compile Atmosphere GWT client side

Tags: java, gwt, atmosphere

I am trying to create Atmosphere client side using GWT. 
I added

```
atmosphere-annotations-2.4.3.jar
atmosphere-gwt20-client-2.4.2.jar
atmosphere-gwt-common-2.4.2.jar
atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar
```

to the buildpath, inserted

```
<inherits name="org.atmosphere.gwt20.AtmosphereGwt20"/>
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.core.Core'/>
<inherits name="com.google.web.bindery.autobean.AutoBean"/>
```

to the projectname.get.xml

I try to initiate call to server like

```
GwtRpcClientSerializer rpc_serializer = GWT.create(GwtRpcClientSerializer.class);
// or
// RPCSerializer rpc_serializer = GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class);

AtmosphereRequestConfig jerseyRpcRequestConfig = AtmosphereRequestConfig.create(rpc_serializer);
jerseyRpcRequestConfig.setUrl(GWT.getHostPageBaseURL() + "it/more/atmosphere");
jerseyRpcRequestConfig.setTransport(AtmosphereRequestConfig.Transport.WEBSOCKET);
jerseyRpcRequestConfig.setFallbackTransport(AtmosphereRequestConfig.Transport.STREAMING);
```

and at GWT compile I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.gwt.user.rebind.rpc.SerializableTypeOracleBuilder.<init>(Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/TreeLogger;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/PropertyOracle;Lcom/google/gwt/core/ext/GeneratorContext;)V
     [java]     at org.atmosphere.gwt20.rebind.SerializerGenerator.generateIncrementally(SerializerGenerator.java:87)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:754)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:160)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:79)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:276)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:265)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.java:87)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createStaticRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:485)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.createRebindExpression(UnifyAst.java:443)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.handleMagicMethodCall(UnifyAst.java:576)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.impl.UnifyAst$UnifyVisitor.endVisit(UnifyAst.java:306)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall.traverse(JMethodCall.java:248)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.traverse(JModVisitor.java:381)
     [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JModVisitor.accept(JModVisitor.java:293)
     [java]     ... 40 more
     [java]       [ERROR] at FilePresenter.java(137): GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class)
     [java]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JMethodCall
     [java]       [ERROR] at FilePresenter.java(137): (RPCSerializer) GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class)
     [java]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JCastOperation
     [java]       [ERROR] at FilePresenter.java(137): RPCSerializer rpc_serializer = (RPCSerializer) GWT.create(RPCSerializer.class)
     [java]          com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.ast.JDeclarationStatement
     [java]       [ERROR] at FilePresenter.java(122): {
```

or

```
[java]       [ERROR] Line 137: Failed to resolve 'org.atmosphere.gwt20.client.GwtRpcClientSerializer' via deferred binding
[java]    [WARN] For the following type(s), generated source was never committed (did you forget to call commit()?)
```

I followed sample code for GWT. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that project has problems with GWT 2.7. Somewhere I found advice to compile it with client jar version 2.3.2-get27 and it worked with jars

```
atmosphere-annotations-2.4.3.jar
atmosphere-gwt20-client-2.3.2-gwt27.jar
atmosphere-gwt20-common-2.3.2-gwt27.jar
atmosphere-runtime-2.4.3.jar
```

and only

```
<inherits name="org.atmosphere.gwt20.AtmosphereGwt20"/>
```

inside projectname.gwt.xml

Currently I'm facing problem with

```
Atmosphere atmosphere = Atmosphere.create();
```

which remains `null` but that's another thing to look at (I suppose).

Comment: If you are happy to use earlier versions, I have seen atmosphere gwt client working fine with version till 2.4.0. Even I have seen same exception with latest version 2.4.2/2.4.3 will update you if I found any solution/work around it